# Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression "<=" operators

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT 
a.StudentsID, 
a.ClassGroup, 
a.FinalGrade, 
COUNT(*) AS ranknumber

FROM FinalAVG AS a 
INNER JOIN FinalAVG AS b 
ON (a.ClassGroup = b.ClassGroup) 
AND (a.FinalGrade <= b.FinalGrade)

GROUP BY 
a.ClassGroup, 
a.StudentsID, 
a.FinalGrade

HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY a.ClassGroup, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

It works well. However when I switch to design view, it shows me the following error

```
Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression a.FinalGrade <= 
b.FinalGrade
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's by design and a limitation of the GUI designer.

However, the SQL view is available for this type of queries.

Yes, just go ahead and correct errors if any. As is, your SQL seems valid.

Comment: So, it means nothing to do and go ahead ?

Comment: Thank you for a down vote. I'm the inventor of Access, so I deserve it.

Comment: Thank you  Gustav, and sorry for the down vote by others

Answer (score 0):

Ms Access Design view can only handle queries where both path part of the join are of the same datatype and there is equality between them e.g

```
ON  A.ID = B.ID
```

But on the SQL view you can do a;l kind of associations..a very common case is when one part is of String DataType (but numeric) and the other is Integer so you can join them like this :

```
A.ID = Cint(B.ID)
```

Comment: I have changed the line  `a.FinalGrade <= b.FinalGrade` to `a.FinalGrade <= Cint(b.FinalGrade)`, still the same error appears

Comment: Do you mean in the Designer View ...this is normal...you can't  use anything else besides equal `=`

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered Microsoft Access currently allows the ChrW(-257) character, which is equivalent to ChrW(65279), to be in field names.  This is a zero-width no-break space character, so it is invisible.  You have to use the AscW() function to detect this character in a string.  Having this character in the field name in one table and not in another table can cause the false error message, "Access can't represent the join expression [table1].[field] = [table2].[field].", when you attempt to view a query in Design View.  If you print such a field name in the Immediate window of the Visual Basic window, with an expression like:

? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tablename").Fields("fieldname").Name

then the ChrW(65279) character appears as a question mark at the start of the field name.

The ChrW(65279) character can also appear in the SQL text of queries.

In hexadecimal, the -257 or 65279 character code is FEFF, which is used to signify the endianness of text.  Someone might have copied and pasted a field name that contains this character from another program into Microsoft Access.

Comment: I forgot to add that you can correct the field name by typing something like the following in the Immediate Window of Visual Basic:   CurrentDb.TableDefs("tablename").Fields("fieldname").Name = "fieldname"

Comment: It's easier to go into the table design and temporarily rename the erroneous field name to a new name, save the table, exit the table designer, go back into the table designer, and manually type in the correct field name, save the table, and exit the table designer.